# Matching each element in a list to each element in a list of a list, using Python

Tags: python, list, data-analysis

I am trying to find the most efficient way of matching each element in a List to each element in a List of Lists using Python. For e.g input:

```
>>>myList = [['hi', 'no', 'bye', 'Global', 24],['morning', 'X', 'place'],['so', 'large', 'mall','test'], ['hi', 'X', 'place', 'bye']]
>>>check_against_myLIst = ['bye','place','hi','australia']
```

Now I am not sure if the best way would be to use a map function, for loops or any other python data analysis methodology.

The output needs to be converted into a dataframe, such that Output is.

```
Index   Value                                      Result
0       ['hi', 'no', 'bye', 'Global', 24]          True
1       ['morning', 'X', 'place']                  True
2       ['so', 'large', 'mall','test']             False
3       ['hi', 'X', 'place', 'bye']                True
```

Thanks !

Comment: Never give your variables the name that are python's builtin functions.

Comment: I think you may have tuples and lists confused slightly...

Comment: Why is the result True for index 3?

Comment: @timgeb because for index 3 the value contains 'hi' & 'bye'. For it to be true the value must contain an element which exists in `check_against_myList`

Comment: @helloWorld ok. Next time please add your specification of what you want to do to the question.

Comment: you need remove element "bye" on array index(2) to get false.

Answer (score 0):

You can just store the result in a list and construct a dataframe from that

```
result = [False]*len(myList)
for n, _list in enumerate(myList):
    if [i for i in _list if i in check_against_myLIst]:
        result[n] = True
```

Comment: This yields `[True, True, True, True]` but OP has `[True, True, False, True]`. You may be correct as I'm confused by what the OP is matching to what.

Comment: I made a mistake in the OP and have now fixed it, so should output [True, True, False, True] now.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a function that tests intersections between sets of your list and the compared list.

**Given**

```
import pandas as pd


cmp = ["bye","place","hi","australia"]
lst = [
    ["hi", "no", "bye", "Global", 24],
    ["morning", "X", "place"],
    ["so", "large", "mall","test"], 
    ["hi", "X", "place", "bye"]
]
```

**Code**

```
def is_in(nested, compare):
    """Return a tuple of (row, bool), True if the compared list intersects."""
    compared = set(compare)
    return [(x, bool(set(x) & compared)) for x in nested]
```

```
bool_lst = is_in(lst, cmp)
bool_lst
```

Output

```
[(['hi', 'no', 'bye', 'Global', 24], True),
 (['morning', 'X', 'place'], True),
 (['so', 'large', 'mall', 'test'], False),
 (['hi', 'X', 'place', 'bye'], True)]
```

It looks similar to your output.  From here, we just need to make a DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(bool_lst, columns=["Value", "Result"])
df.rename_axis("Index")
```

Output

[image]

The latter can all be reduced to a single line:

```
pd.DataFrame([(x, bool(set(x) & set(cmp))) for x in lst], columns=["Value", "Result"]).rename_axis("Index")
```

Answer (score 0):

First, create sets from `myList`, for the O(1) membership test.

```
>>> myList = [['hi', 'no', 'bye', 'Global', 24],['morning', 'X', 'place'],['so', 'large', 'mall','test'], ['hi', 'X', 'place', 'bye']]
>>> checks = ['bye','place','hi','australia'] # renamed from check_against_myLIst
>>> sets = map(set, myList)
```

Use efficient `any` checks to find out whether any element of `checks` is in a given set. (As opposed to computing intersections, `any` is lazy.)

```
>>> result = [(lst, any(s in set_ for s in check)) for lst, set_ in zip(myList, sets)]
```

Build the dataframe.

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(result, columns=['Value', 'Result'])
>>> df.index.name = 'Index'
df

                           Value  Result
Index                                   
0      [hi, no, bye, Global, 24]    True
1            [morning, X, place]    True
2        [so, large, mall, test]   False
3            [hi, X, place, bye]    True
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have example about the way you can get it without use pandas. 
Anyway, let me explain another point of view:

```
# list
my_list = (['hi', 'no', 'bye', 'Global', 24],['morning', 'X', 'place'],['so', 'large', 'mall','test','TESSTTTT'], ['hi', 'X', 'place', 'bye'])

# check list
check_against_myLIst = ('bye','place','hi','australia')

# Function to find intersection of two arrays
def interSection(index, arr1,arr2):
    result = 'false'
    output = list(filter(lambda x: x in arr1, arr2))
    if output:
        result = 'true'

    print 'index',"\t"*1,'Value',"\t"*6,'Result'
    print index,"\t"*1,arr1,"\t"*4,result
    print  ''

# Driver program
if __name__ == "__main__":
    count = 0
    for arrayItem in my_list:
        interSection(count, arrayItem,check_against_myLIst)
        count += 1
```